# n-th derivative of exponential function $\;e^{-f(x)}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Is there a closed-form expression for $n$-th derivative of exponential function below ($n>0$)?
$$
\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\large e^{-f(x)}
$$

Comment: Sure: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See [Faa di Bruno's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula) generalizing the chain rule to higher derivatives:

$${d^n \over dx^n} f(g(x))=\sum \frac{n!}{m_1!\,1!^{m_1}\,m_2!\,2!^{m_2}\,\cdots\,m_n!\,n!^{m_n}}\cdot f^{(m_1+\cdots+m_n)}(g(x))\cdot \prod_{j=1}^n\left(g^{(j)}(x)\right)^{m_j}$$

where the sum is over all $n$-tuples of nonnegative integers $(m_1, …, m_n)$ satisfying the constraint
$$1\cdot m_1+2\cdot m_2+3\cdot m_3+\cdots+n\cdot m_n=n.\,$$

If you're familiar with [Bell polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomial) $B_{n,k}(x_1,...,x_{n−k+1})$:, the identity can be simplified as follows:
$${d^n \over dx^n} f(g(x)) = \sum_{k=1}^n f^{(k)}(g(x))\cdot B_{n,k}\left(g'(x),g''(x),\dots,g^{(n-k+1)}(x)\right).$$

In the formulae above, of course, $f$ is the exponential function, and $g(x)$ serves as your $-f(x)$.

With $f(x) = e^x$, all of the derivatives of $f$ are the same, and are a factor common to every term.

Comment: .....drum roll - 100K!!! Lights Flashing - +1 :-)

Comment: @Amzoti - Thank you!! Right on the nose!

Comment: Really CONGRATULATIONS! That is a really awesome accomplishment and I am happy for you as you deserve it! Now, go get some rest and think about TG and XMAS and NY! :-)

Comment: Yes, indeed, @Amzoti Time to focus on the holidays and ... my life!