# 100th derivative of $e^{-x^2}$ at point $0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Problem: 
Find
$\frac{\mathrm d^{100}}{\mathrm dx^{100}}e^{-x^2}$ at point $0$.

My attempt:
$y'=-2xe^{-x^2}$
I tried to use General Leibniz rule and I didn't get much better information.

Without: Taylor series

Comment: Taylor series maybe?

Comment: $$\frac{100!}{50!}$$

Comment: With $99$ (or $101$) in place of $100$, the problem would be much easier

Comment: It is the value of $H_{100}(0),$ by definition of Hermite polynomials https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials (physicist's ones). I confirm the value given by @Ian Miller

Comment: Any particular reason you can't use Taylor series? The general Leibniz rule would conceivably work, but series are far quicker.

Comment: I haven't learn Taylor series yet.

Comment: Francesco Faà di Bruno formulat here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula and a special case close to this problem is here:  here:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/577158/n-th-derivative-of-exponential-function-e-fx

Comment: $\frac {\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}(p(x)e^{-x^2})=(p'(x)-2xp(x))e^{-x^2}$ gives an iteration on the "prefix"-polynomials, but unless someone recognizes those a some famous well known things, only way I see is computing brute force the coefficients. Edit: I see @JeanMarie has recognized those as (slight variant) of Hermite polynomials already.

Answer (score 10):

Since the most obvious approach is forbidden I propose the following (large) detour:

It is well known that the Fourier transform of a Gaussian is again a Gaussian. E.g., one has
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-t^2/2}\cos(\omega t)\>dt=\sqrt{2\pi}e^{-\omega^2/2}\qquad(\omega\in{\mathbb R})\ .$$
Putting $\omega:=x\sqrt{2}$ and substituting $t:=\tau/\sqrt{2}$ leads to
$$f(x):=e^{-x^2}={1\over 2\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\tau^2/4}\cos(x\tau)\>d\tau=
{1\over \sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^\infty e^{-\tau^2/4}\cos(x\tau)\>d\tau\ .$$
Since we are working here in the Schwartz space ${\cal S}$ we may differentiate a hundred times under the integral sign and obtain
$$f^{(100)}(x)={1\over \sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^\infty \tau^{100}e^{-\tau^2/4}\cos(x\tau)\>d\tau\ .$$
Putting $x:=0$ here and substituting $\tau:=2\sqrt{u}$ leads to
$$f^{(100)}(0)={2^{100}\over \sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^\infty e^{-u} u^{99/2}\>du={2^{100}\Gamma(101/2)\over\sqrt{\pi}}={100!\over50!}\ .$$

Comment: What's the difference between a Taylor series and a (converging) exponential series?

Comment: "You have to use *something" about the exponential function." Sure, but as by the question not Taylor series. Comment by @JeanMarie gives a hint how to do without.

Comment: @GyroGearloose: Naming the $p_n$-things Hermite polynomials does not solve the concrete problem at hand.

Comment: (+1) a bit advanced for someone who has not had Taylor series, but a good answer nonetheless.

Answer (score 8):

Since
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^{n-1}\\
&=e^x
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}e^x\\
&=e^x
\end{align}
$$
we can interchange derivatives with limits of $\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$.

Using the Binomial Theorem, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\left.\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)^{100}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n}\right)^n\right|_{x=0}
&=\left.\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)^{100}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\frac{x^{2k}}{n^k}\right|_{x=0}\\
&=\binom{n}{50}\frac{100!}{n^{50}}
\end{align}
$$
Taking the limit, we get
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\binom{n}{50}\frac{100!}{n^{50}}=\frac{100!}{50!}
$$

Answer (score 1):

You started well..
So you basically got $$y'=-2xy$$

Now we have:
$$y'+2xy=0$$
Use Leibniz formula after differentiating the expression $n$ times (to get some recursive formula):
$$y^{(n)}+2\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n\choose k}{x^{(k)}y^{(n-k)}}=0$$

The sum expression holds only for $k=0,1$ and for $k\ge 2$ it will be $0$ because you differentiate $x$ more then once.

So, it yields, after some calculation: 
$$y^{(n)}+2(xy^{(n-1)}+(n-1)y^{(n-2)})=0$$

You are looking for the $100$-th derivative at $x=0$ so plug it in and you get
$$y^{(n)}(0)=-2(n-1)y^{(n-2)}(0)$$

Now it is over:
$$y^{(100)}(0)=-198y^{(98)}(0)=198\times194\times y^{(96)}(0)=\cdots =\prod_{k=1}^{50}({2+4(k-1)})\times y(0)=\prod_{k=1}^{50}({2+4(k-1)})$$

The product expression you get is actually the expression for arithmetic sequence $2, 6, 10, 14, \ldots , 194, 198$ and it is easy to find that $198$ is $50$-th element of the sequence (that's also why is the expression positive).