# Finding the nth derivative of a function

Tags: derivatives

Recently I am working on a project. It requires the nth derivative of the function $e^{i\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\lambda}}z}$ with respect to $\lambda$. Or equivalently, finding the nth order Taylor series near $\lambda=0$ to nth order. Using mathematica to expand it to 3rd order, we can get 
\begin{align}
e^{i z}-\frac{1}{2} i \lambda  e^{i z} z-\frac{1}{8} \lambda ^2 \left(e^{i z} z (z-3
   i)\right)+\frac{1}{48} \lambda ^3 e^{i z} z \left(i z^2+9 z-15 i\right)+O\left(\lambda
   ^4\right)
\end{align}
If we type the following to mathematica

SeriesCoefficient[E^(I 1/Sqrt[1 + [Lambda]] z) , {[Lambda], 0, n}]

It will also give some complicated expression. Is it possible to get a closed form of the nth derivative?

Comment: Have you tried this yet? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/577158/n-th-derivative-of-exponential-function-e-fx

Comment: as for the n-th derivative of $i/\sqrt{1+\lambda}$, that can be found by expanding $(1+\lambda)^{-1/2}$ with Newton binomial theorem.

Comment: This one is really helpful! Let me try it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

My answer is as follows:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\operatorname{d}^n}{\operatorname{d}x^n} \operatorname{e}^{\operatorname{i}\frac1{\sqrt{1+\lambda}\,}z}
&=\frac{\operatorname{d}^n}{\operatorname{d}x^n} \operatorname{e}^{\operatorname{i}z(1+\lambda)^{-1/2}}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \operatorname{e}^{\operatorname{i}z(1+\lambda)^{-1/2}} B_{n,k}\biggl(\operatorname{i}z(1+\lambda)^{-1/2-1}\biggl\langle-\frac12\biggr\rangle_1, \operatorname{i}z(1+\lambda)^{-1/2-2}\biggl\langle-\frac12\biggr\rangle_2,\\
&\quad\operatorname{i}z(1+\lambda)^{-1/2-3}\biggl\langle-\frac12\biggr\rangle_3, \dotsc, \operatorname{i}z(1+\lambda)^{-1/2-(n-k+1)}\biggl\langle-\frac12\biggr\rangle_{n-k+1}\biggr)\\
&=\operatorname{e}^{\operatorname{i}z(1+\lambda)^{-1/2}} \sum_{k=0}^n (\operatorname{i}z)^k (1+\lambda)^{-k/2-n} B_{n,k}\biggl(\biggl\langle-\frac12\biggr\rangle_1, \biggl\langle-\frac12\biggr\rangle_2, \dotsc, \biggl\langle-\frac12\biggr\rangle_{n-k+1}\biggr)\\
&=\operatorname{e}^{\operatorname{i}z(1+\lambda)^{-1/2}} \sum_{k=0}^n (\operatorname{i}z)^k (1+\lambda)^{-k/2-n} \sum _{\ell=k}^n s(n,\ell) \biggl(-\frac12\biggr)^\ell S(\ell,k)\\
&\to \operatorname{e}^{\operatorname{i}z} \sum_{k=0}^n (\operatorname{i}z)^k \sum _{\ell=k}^n s(n,\ell) \biggl(-\frac12\biggr)^\ell S(\ell,k), \quad \lambda\to0,
\end{align*}
where $s(n,\ell)$ and $S(\ell,k)$ denote the Stirling numbers of the first and second kinds respectively. Therefore, we obtain the power series expansion
\begin{equation*}
\operatorname{e}^{\operatorname{i}\frac1{\sqrt{1+\lambda}\,}z}
=\operatorname{e}^{\operatorname{i}z} \sum_{n=0}^\infty\Biggl[\sum_{k=0}^n (\operatorname{i}z)^k \sum _{\ell=k}^n s(n,\ell) \biggl(-\frac12\biggr)^\ell S(\ell,k)\Biggr]\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}, \quad |\lambda|<1.
\end{equation*}

References

1. Siqintuya Jin, Bai-Ni Guo, and Feng Qi, *Partial Bell polynomials, falling and rising factorials, Stirling numbers, and combinatorial identities*, Computer Modeling in Engineering & Sciences **132** (2022), no. 3, 781--799; available online at https://doi.org/10.32604/cmes.2022.019941.
2. F. Qi, X.-T. Shi, F.-F. Liu, and D. V. Kruchinin, *Several formulas for special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind and applications*, J. Appl. Anal. Comput. **7** (2017), no. 3, 857--871; available online at https://doi.org/10.11948/2017054.
3. Feng Qi, *Taylor's series expansions for real powers of two functions containing squares of inverse cosine function, closed-form formula for specific partial Bell polynomials, and series representations for real powers of Pi*, Demonstratio Mathematica **55** (2022), no. 1, 710--736; available online at https://doi.org/10.1515/dema-2022-0157.
4. Feng Qi, Da-Wei Niu, Dongkyu Lim, and Yong-Hong Yao, *Special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind for some sequences and functions*, Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications **491** (2020), no. 2, Paper No. 124382, 31 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2020.124382.